# laravel 5 show related data to logged in user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In a Laravel 5 project I am trying to display to a logged in user the details of their lesson packages.
I am trying to use a where clause that gets the desired info. It seems that I can't get relationship data from the collection that I am getting back.
I am lost and am requesting some guidance. I can't seem to find any info pertaining to this kind of problem.

The current error:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$players (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/views/auth/account/mylessonhours.blade.php)

My Controller:

```
 public function getMyLessonhours(Lessonhours $lessonhours, Packages $packages)
{
    $packages = Packages::all();
    $lessonhours = Lessonhours::whereHas('players', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('users_id', '=', Auth::user());
    })->with('players')->get();
    return view('auth.account.mylessonhours', compact('lessonhours'), compact('packages'));
}
```

My Relationships:
Users:

```
 public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Players', 'users_id');
}
```

Players:

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'users_id');
}
```

Lessonhours:

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Players', 'players_id');
}

public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Packages', 'packages_id');
}

public function hoursused()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Hoursused', 'lessonhours_id');
}
```

And the part of the view that fails

```
 <h3>{{ $lessonhours->players->getFullName($lessonhours->players_id) }}</h3>  
                        {{ $lessonhours->players->gender }}<br>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn- pull-right">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                                   Edit {{ $lessonhours->players->getFullName($lessonhours->players->id) }}</a>
                       Birthdate: {{ $lessonhours->players->birthdate->format('m-d-Y') }}<br>

                       Family: {{ $lessonhours->players->users->famname }}<br>
                       <hr>
```

Thank you for help.

UDATE:
After doing a dd($lessonhours); I got the following data in the collection which does show the desired info, I just continue to get the 'undefined' error above:

```
  Collection {#216 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Lessonhours {#202 ▼
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      +table: "lessonhours"
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "players_id" => 2
        "packages_id" => 2
        "signup_date" => "2016-06-01"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-19 03:31:11"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-19 03:31:11"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "players" => Players {#220 ▼
          +table: "players"
          #fillable: array:4 [▶]
          #dates: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "users_id" => 2
            "fname" => "Girltest"
            "lname" => "Testfam"
            "gender" => "Female"
            "birthdate" => "2010-10-04"
            "created_at" => "2016-11-19 03:30:56"
            "updated_at" => "2016-11-19 03:30:56"
          ]
          #original: array:8 [▶]
          #relations: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:
The error occurs with the following line:

```
 <h3>{{ $lessonhours->players->getFullName($lessonhours->players_id) }}</h3>
```

The code works, but I only want one parent record. 
[image: Too many parent records]

Comment: Auth:user() dosent return id...you need Auth::id() or Auth::user()->id;

Comment: @wdarnellg are you using for each for `lessonhours` in view ? since you have used `get()` method to retrieve data it will have an array of collection irrespective of number of results. That might cause the problem

Comment: @jaysingkar That was the issue. Adding "@foreach" got the data to display. Thank you. I would welcome a more elegant way to do the same thing if there is one. ;-) How do I mark this as answer?

Comment: i will post this as an answer... You can also use `first()` method instead of `get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get()` method returns the array of collection irrespective of number of results. If you are expecting only single result you can use `first()` method.

```
$lessonhours = Lessonhours::whereHas('players', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('users_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    })->with('players')->first();
```

Or use `for each` loop while rendering in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an ID from user object, so change you query to:

```
$lessonhours = Lessonhours::whereHas('players', function($q) {
        $q->where('users_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })->with('players')->get();
```

Comment: I did a dd($lessonhours); using both queries with the same result. I have the expected data from the lessonhours and players tables.

Comment: The error is the same. I am not able to show the related Players data in the view.

Comment: And what do you get when using `dd($lessonhours)` if you put it right after the query code? If it has data, please post it somewhere.

Comment: I have posted a Update to my question above.

Comment: Thanks. Please also check what the exact line that fails.

Comment: I added the failing line of code above. It is line 21 if that matters.

Comment: I had to step away for a couple of days and am back on this project. It is working pretty well, except that because of the "@foreach", the parent record gets repeated each time a  child record is added. How can I bypass the "@foreach" or at least show the parent record only once? I am updating the question above with a screenshot.

Comment: Since the query is working as it is supposed to, I will address the new issue in a different question. Sorry for any inconvenience.